# Dapper is converting my dates into 01-Jan-01 and I cannot see why?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and Dapper v1.50.5.

I have a standard query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TsData].[ImportingLogs] 
WHERE ImportContextGuid = '{3c19d706-0895-49e4-b96c-38eb6a3cc579}'
```

which returns some data:

[image]

and the `CreationTime` column I am interested in has valid datetimes.

The table is simply defined as:

[image]

The POCO is:

```
public class OzCsImportingLogsTableModel
{
    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
    public int? CreatorUserId { get; set; }
    public int? DeleterUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeletionTime { get; set; }
    public int DurationMs { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ImportContextGuid { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }
    public int? LastModifierUserId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public OzCsImportManagerMessageKindEnum MessageKindId { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string StructuredData { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

and the Dapper call is:

```
DbContext.Execute($"[{Schema}].[usp_ImportingQueue_FinaliseImport]", storedProcParams, aCommandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

However when I look at `OzCsImportingLogsTableModel.CreationTime`, the value is always `01-Jan-01 00:00:00` which indicates the value is NULL.

I don't understand this. Can someone point me in the right direction here please?

Comment: Is it because your database field is `CreationTime` and your model property is `CreationDateTime`? Disclaimer: I've never used Dapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John has it correct in his comment. The name of the property (here `CreationDateTime`) generally must match the name of the column (here `CreationTime`). Having that said, it is not really the name of the table column, but the name of the result column, so you could do something like this:

```
SELECT CreationTime as CreationDateTime, ...
```

if you can modify the actual query.

As commented by @fstam: the behavoir is that 01-jan-01 is the default value of a DateTime and since it's a non-nullable type and never set to anything by dapper, it is the value shown.

Note that the logic applied to find the member for a column name is available [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/4e62055c5775aced61b848282ed180de0ab62161/Dapper/DefaultTypeMap.cs#L153):

> // preference order is:
>   exact match over underscore match, exact
>   case over wrong case, backing fields over regular fields,
>   match-inc-underscores over match-exc-underscores

In your case, however none of the above applies; it is probably best to adjust the name of the property in code.

*Update:*

Another thing that I just saw: the `DurationMs` column in your schema is nullable, but the `DurationMs` property is not. You might want to define
this property as `public int? DurationMs { get; set; }` instead.
(I haven't checked all members).

Comment: Further explanation towards the behavoir is that 01-jan-01 is the default value of a DateTime and since it's a non-nullable type and never set to anything by dapper, it is the value shown.